# delete all symbols in the wordthat is equals last symbol in the word

Tags: java, string

How to delete all symbols in the wordthat is equals last symbol in the word? 
As example: word is "alphabeta" and return word must be "lphbet".

```
private static StringBuilder deleteAllChars(StringBuilder arr, String a)
{
    StringBuilder tmp=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
    {
        tmp = arr.deleteCharAt(arr.indexOf(a));
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

But this function doesn't work well.

Comment: What does "doesn't work fine" mean? What happens when you run it?

Comment: func doesn't work with all words the same... tree->tr but saw->s ...

Comment: but now i have understand how to do it :) thanks all repliers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [**String#replace()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
String str="alphabeta";
System.out.println(str.replace(str.substring(str.length()-1), ""));
```

---

```
Output:   lphbet
```